# Using Elixir pipeline to transform a string into a map

Tags: elixir

Consider the list of string values,

```
lines = ["foo: 1", "bar: 2", "baz: 3"]
```

That one might transform into the Elixir map,

```
%{ "foo": "1", "bar": "2", "baz": "3"}
```

using a simple `Enum.reduce`,

```
Enum.reduce(lines, %{}, fn(line, result) ->
  [key, value] = String.split(line, ": ")
  Map.put(result, key, value)
end)
```

How might one refactor this into something more succinct, specifically with the third argument passed to `reduce`? For example, my instinct wants to do something like,

```
Enum.reduce(lines, %{}, fn(line, result) ->
  String.split(line, ": ") |> Map.put(result)
end)
```

but the Elixir pipe operator doesn't allow piping multiple values nor piping them to anything other than the first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an anonymous function

```
Enum.reduce(lines, %{}, fn(line, result) ->
  String.split(line, ": ")
  |> (fn(x) -> Map.put(result, hd(x), List.last(x)) end).()
end)
```

You can also do it like this

```
Enum.reduce(lines, [], fn(line, result) -> result ++ String.split(line, ": ") end)
  |> Enum.chunk(2)
  |> Map.new(fn [k,  v] -> {k, v} end)
```

which I less efficient, because it does 2 iterations, but I think it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

This would also be solvable with a map instead of a reduce

```
lines
|> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, ": "))
|> Map.new(&List.to_tuple/1)
```